# Why can not getline?

Tags: c++

Why can not getline()?
Is it because of the string left in the buffer? I also acted to remove the buffer in doubt. But it's impossible. Do you know why?

```
int len;
    cout << "input length : ";
    cin >> len;

    int* intPass = new int[len];
    int* intSolu = new int[len];

    string strPass;

    getline(cin, strPass);

    cout << strPass;

    cout << "intPass output : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cin >> intPass[i];
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `new[]`? Why do you expect a user to input a length? Why do you want to output a `std::string` char by char? [The C++ Programming Language](https://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-4th/dp/0321563840/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8)

Comment: @Swordfish where do you see the OP output a string char by char ?

Comment: @bruno misread the code. read `cin` for `cout`.

Comment: @Swordfish where ? in "cin >> intPass[i];" ? I do not think, notice _inPass_ is only initialized from "cin >> intPass[i];". You are wrong, and if you DV me because of that you are double wrong ...

Comment: @bruno it doesn't matter, it's bs anyway.

Comment: @Swordfish and it an array of _int_ rather than _char_ as you supposed. Probably the best is to remove all these remarks ?

Comment: `#include <limits>` and `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after `cin >> len;` and before `getline(cin, strPass);` to remove all extraneous characters from `stdin` before you call `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can not getline?

When you input the value for *input length* you enter a number and a newline, that newline is get by *getline*

If you entered for instance *123 aze qsd* then *strPass* will be " aze qsd"

So you get a line, but not the expected one

If you want to flush all after the number on the same line you can double *getline* call

For instance also modifying your code to see more  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int len;
  cout << "input length : ";
  cin >> len;

  int* intPass = new int[len];
  int* intSolu = new int[len];

  string strPass;

  getline(cin, strPass);
  getline(cin, strPass);

  cout << "strPass is " << strPass << endl;

  cout << "intPass input :" << endl; // it is an input, not an output
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cin >> intPass[i];
  }

  cout << "intPass output is" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cout << intPass[i] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
c.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cc:13:8: warning: unused variable ‘intSolu’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int* intSolu = new int[len];
        ^~~~~~~
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
input length : 3
aze qsd
strPass is aze qsd
intPass input :
11
22
33
intPass output is
11
22
33
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I encourage you to check if `cin >> len` success and if yes to check the value of *len*, for instance :

```
if (!(cin >> len) || (len < 0)) {
  cout << "invalid length" << endl;
  return -1.
}
```

Comment: doesn't address the man issues with that code.

Comment: @Swordfish you are wrong supposing an issue where there is not ... except in your way to read the OP code ;-)

Comment: You are right -- I'm getting old and just thought my bi-focals were to blame `:)` I didn't even snap to the fact that there were two of them there.